# Swift - Background Fetch and Delay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I implemented Background Fetch feature in my App.

The function called by background fetch includes a delayed function.

However this function doesn't seem to trigger :

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    MyFunction()
}
```

It seems to trigger however as soon as I wake up the app.

Why this doesn't trigger on background fetch ?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a delay to *wait* for something has finished, don't do that.

Comment: What's the expected result? waiting (delay) and then executing `MyFunction()` or the opposite?

Comment: Oh yes I should have mentioned I was aware it was a crappy practice but still It would be good enough in my case : )

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, wait x secondes then execute MyFunction is the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.MyFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
        RunLoop.current.run()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can run in the background on the main queue.  Try this (changed `main` to `global()`):

```
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 2 
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
    MyFunction()
}
```